# Urgent help - Place Order button is not working on click. Nothing happens and no errors logged for Magento 2.4.0

Tags: magento2, cart, payment, place-order, magento2.4.0

I am getting complaints from few users that when they go to **Checkout** and click on `"Place Order"` button nothing happens.

I tried adding lots of debug and system logs but no errors or issues logged.

I tried testing from my end using testers across devices and it's working from them, so I am not able to replicate the issue.

Has anyone faced this? What could be the issue? How to fix this?

Please urgent help needed

Comment: any browser console errors?

Comment: If the button is not **working** it must trigger some error on browser console. If you can add the console error logs then we can estimate what's wrong.